# My navigation bar displays poorly in Internet Exploreer and Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, nav

I am working on what will become my personal website, and I would like a navigation bar with icons that scales to fit well on a laptop or a desktop.  I have it working well in Firefox at: jakgrueneberg.com/testing , but it is horribly broken in IE and Chrome.  I don't understand why there should be such a drastic difference.

HTML:

```
    <div class="navigation" id="navbox">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="logo"><img src="images/logo.jpg"></li>
                <li data-slide="1"><img src="images/bio.png" width="100%"></li>
                <li data-slide="2"><img src="images/skills.png" width="100%"</li>
                <li data-slide="3"><img src="images/resume.png" width="100%"</li>
                <li data-slide="4"><img src="images/contact.png" width="100%"</li>
                <li><img src="images/circles.png" width="100%"></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#navbox {
        background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
        color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
        height:7%;
        position:fixed;
        top:0px;
        right:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:8%;
    }
nav {
        width:35%;
        background:#333;
        display:inline-table;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:2px;
        border-radius:3px;
        float:left;
        margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding:0px 0px 0px 2.5px;
    }
.logo {
        width:7%;
        margin:0px 10px 0px 2px;
    }
nav ul li{
        background:#cacaca;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px #333;
        width:17%;
        height:100%;
        float:center;
        margin:0px 2px 0px 0px;
        padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:0.5px;
        border-radius:3px;
        display:inline-block;

    }
nav ul li:hover {
        background-color:#333;
    }
* { 
    font-family:Ubuntu;
    height:100%;
}
```

I have some JS to make waypoints work and to keep my logo square, but I don't think they should matter here.

Any ideas on how to adapt/ workaround this for IE and Chrome?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set a global `height` attribute to `100%` in your overwrite section. This is effectively forcing your `img` tag within the `li` to display at 100%.

Rather, set that to `height:auto;` and you should be good to go...

Comment: your welcome. Feel free to +1. Also of note, take a look into this document. it is a great launchpad for formatting css...https://github.com/necolas/idiomatic-css